# Avoid removing duplicate posts

Tags: wp-query, loop

I have an arrays of **IDs** which may contain duplicate values.

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 24
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 60
    [3] => 11
)
```

I'd like to loop through those IDs using **WP Query** and the `post__in` property.

```php
Array
(
    'post__in'  => $posts,
    'post_type' => 'any,
    'orderby'   => 'post__in'
)
```

Everything work as expected, but duplicate IDs are removed by default.
Is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit less efficient, but if you have an array of IDs, possibly including duplicates, and want to get the posts for each, I'd suggest use `get_post()` on each ID, giving you an array of posts.

```
$post_ids = [ 24, 11, 60, 11 ];
$posts    = array_map( 'get_post', $post_ids );

global $post;

foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
    // the_title(); etc.
endforeach;
```

Comment: That would actually work, thank you. But by using this approach I wouldn't be able to setup a pagination, as I'm not using the WP loop.